# how to select 2 sql tables together?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I havew for example 'employees' table and 'phones' tables , now i select them together

```
SELECT employees.*, phones.*
FROM employees JOIN
     phones
     ON employees.id = phones.id
```

after the fetch:
now the question is how to show it in table by using PHP foreach loop maybe,
no matter while there are 'employees' that have few phones at the phones table
and thats mean that there are few phones with the same id,
how do i combine all the phones with the same id that equal the employees id to one column ?

Comment: Your `JOIN` conditions are probably not correct.  I would be really surprised if the `id`s were the matching column between the two tables.

Comment: Probably `group by` and `group_concat`... assuming you already are getting results but they are multi rows. You also don't need the dual `table.*` you can just do `*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use any option

SELECT employees.*, phones.*
FROM employees INNER JOIN      phones      ON employees.id = phones.employe_id

SELECT employees.*, phones.*
FROM employees LEFT JOIN      phones      ON employees.id = phones.employe_id

SELECT employees.*, phones.*
FROM employees OUTER JOIN      phones      ON employees.id = phones.employe_id

Comment: you can use (+)=   for left join      =(+) for right join also

Answer (score 0):

Please make your tables are design in a right way

There should be always primary key on Tables and second table should have foreign key to join

and we have different join

```
inner join
outter left join
Outter right join
```

[https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp][1]